# How can i display movies in profile page, added by an user?

Tags: custom-post-types, users

How can i display movies added by an editor in profile page, i mention that the user (editors) have capabilities to add movies.

I shoud use a querry? with args?

I mention that the 
post_type is "post" - for movies ////// "trailers" - for trailers

I want to get movies and trailers on the profile user page. How can i do that?

```
----------------------------------- UPDATED -------------------
    <?php
    global 
    $current_user; 
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    $recentPosts = new WP_Query();
    $recentPosts->query(array(
        'author' => $current_user->ID,
        'post_type' => 'post'));
    ?>
    <?php while ($recentPosts->have_posts()) : $recentPosts->the_post(); ?>

    <div class="bposter">
    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php printf(__('Film %s'), the_title_attribute('echo=0')); ?>">
    <img src="/scripts/timthumb.php?src=<?php the_field('img'); ?>&h=120&w=90&zc=1" alt="" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" /></a>
    <div class="bpt"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php printf(__('Permanent Link to %s', 'kubrick'), the_title_attribute('echo=0')); ?>">
    <?php the_title(); ?>
    </a></div>
    </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    </div>
----------------------------------- UPDATED -------------------
```

Here is an image how it look's
http://s12.postimg.org/ssacplu3x/filme.jpg
Thanks.

Comment: this code is not working, it retrive me the movies but same movies on diferent users...

Comment: 1. `query_posts()` is not recommended. Use `new WP_Query` instead. 2. `$current_user->ID` must not be set. Try a `var_dump($current_user);` to see what is in that variable. Wish I could help more but I am on a deadline for my own project.

Comment: thanks for your answer it seem is working, but how can i retrive all the movies, i retrive only the amount set in Administrtor setings.

How can i retrive the pages too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how can i retrive all the movies, i retrive only the amount set in
>   Administrtor setings. How can i retrive the pages too

Assuming that `$current_user->ID` is now correct, and it seems from your comment that it is.

```
$recentPosts = new WP_Query();
$recentPosts->query(
    array(
        'author' => $current_user->ID,
        'post_type' => array('post','trailers'), // pull both posts and trailers
        'showposts' => -1, // show all posts
        'ignore_sticky_post' => true // my addition, seems like a good idea
    )
);
```

### Reference

https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Parameters

Comment: Nicely commented example. +1